# How to use more texture?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, textures

How can be generated more textures and different images for them?

I looked at this example: http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-vi-textures/

But I can't understand how should I do. Can anyone help me or provide me an example about this?

Comment: That tutorial doesn't even explain how to load the image. So it's no surprise that you don't know how to load images. Oh, it loads it into a Bitmap, but it never handles how to give that Bitmap data to OpenGL with a `glTexImage` call. Consider using [tutorials that actually work](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides).